# How to print out the content of an array without comma and brackets?

Tags: java, arrays

With the following line of code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
```

My output is like this:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 8]
```

And when I simply print out the array:

```
System.out.println(ar);
```

My output is:

```
[I@78f1f2cc
```

How do I print out `2 4 6 8 8` without using a `for` loop?

Comment: Use `Arrays#toString` or `Arrays#deepToString`.

Comment: If you're just interested in an output without commas and brackets you can replace all of them using `.replace`, no?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I used Arrays.toString, however what I want is to print out the content of the array without comma and brackets. How is this a duplicate to the link that you provided? All the answers in the link that you provided use either Arrays.toString or Arrays.deepToString.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19201690/1065197) and adapt it to your needs.